# Wait until a cookie has a value before executing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, asynchronous

I need to wait to run a function until I have a cookie. The setting of the cookie is out of my hands. I'm using the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to retrieve the cookie.

I think the cookie is set after the following is executed:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '//munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true,
    success: function() {
        Munchkin.init('XXX-XXX-XXX');
    }
})
```

On server A, it was enough to place the function call inside the success parameter.

On server B, the cookie is undefined at the time that the "success" function is executed. I also tried the following on server B:

```
var post = $.ajax({
    url: '//munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true,
    success: function() {
        Munchkin.init('XXX-XXX-XXX');
    }
});
post.done(function(p){
    makeLeadCall($.cookie('_mkto_trk'));
});
```

How can I wait until the cookie has a value before executing the function?

Comment: are you sure the cookie is being set ever on B ?

Comment: I think the question we need to ask is "what exactly are you trying to do"?

A cookie is a piece of data returned with an HTTP request - to be sent back to the server on subsequent requests - it's a way for a server to persist data on the client 

It is NOT a tool for passing information to the client for the client's own use - thus when it's "set" isn't something which will be rigidly defined (it just has to be returned)

You may also find using some sort of debug (Devtools->Network) or Proxy/Sniffer (Fiddler) will help you determine IF the cookie is even being sent...